# How to autoload package's classes from within the package?

Tags: php, composer-php

The application layout with my composer package is as follows

```
some-application
├── index.php
└── composer.json
└── vendor/my/package
              ├── composer.json
              └── src
                  ├── Foobar
                  │   └── style.css.php
                  └── Bar
                      ├── Moo.php
                      └── Baz.php
```

`index.php` uses `style.css.php` as a stylesheet in its html markup. The stylesheet is a php file because the styles need to get rendered dynamically. So, `style.css.php` is accessed directly by the clients browser, without passing `index.php` that includes the autoloader.

Now, I would like to access `Moo` and `Baz` in `style.css.php`, but what is the correct approach to define some kind of autoloader for my package that allows this?

I was only able to find info regarding the autoloader that the application would include. But what if I bypass the application's autoloader invocation?

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can add the files to the autoload-section: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you want to provide the files in a web-accessible folder the easiest would probably be to provide some kind of composer post-install-script which will then symlink/copy those files, similar to how Symfony's [`Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L159-L182) used to do it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of the autoload-section, but that does not work in my case. Having the `style.css.php` web accessible, it is good to know about the post-install-script approach, but the vendor folder is web-accessible anyway, so this is not the issue. Maybe I did not understand your suggestion correctly. If so, please give an example on how this can solve my scenario.

Comment: I extended my example. Hope this makes my scenario clearer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your challenge, then. Having your vendor-folder web-accessible might be a security concern, so I figured the issue was to copy/symlink from there to a web folder. Is your problem that the file would only be accessible in a folder structure and not just directly at e.g. `http://example.com/style.css.php`?

Comment: I guess I could make the `style.css.php` accessible in the document root anywhere by symlinking -- to avoid security risks. But my issue is in how to autoload the other classes. Maybe I could just include the composer generated autoloader in the vendor directory - but then I have to make assumptions regarding the directory layout outside of my package. Maybe I should state that I control the package, but not the application. So I am not sure where the `style.css.php` will be symlinked to.

Comment: is style.css.php your own script or another vendor script?

Comment: `style.css.php` is mine. Tried to make it clearer in the example. Might have been irritating previously that I am sure to control my/package but not the application layout.

Comment: So, `style.css.php` needs access to other scripts which need to be required or autoloaded?

Comment: @dbrumann yes, exactly. Requiring them with include statements is easy, but I would like to avoid this. It becomes messy as history has shown. Instead, I want to use autoloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To autoload composer package classes, you just need to somehow load the autoloader.

In your script, you can say:

```
<?php

$path = file_exists('vendor/autoload.php') ? 'vendor/autoload.php' : '../../../autoload.php';
require_once $path;

use Bar\Moo;

$moo = new Moo();
```

This will load the application's autoloader when the package is included in an application, or will load the package's own autoloader when you develop the package, e.g. running tests.

Comment: Given my directory layout, `vendor/autoload.php` would not be a valid path from within `style.css.php`. It is only valid in `index.php`.

Comment: thats cool, just use `../../../vendor/autoload.php` (you might need more `../`'s)

Comment: the issue with using the application's autoloader is that my package code then only works if there is a surrounding application. What if I wanted to run my package code from itself? E.g. unit tests.

Comment: two ways of doing that, either work on your package on its own, or git clone your package into the vendor folder after having deleted the composer installed one, and just composer install from in there. but the unit tests for a package should not run as part of your main projects test suite

Comment: But what include path do I then use in my `style.css.php` file? Your given examples will not work in one of the situations: either it will not work when the package is run/developed on its own (given that I use the `../../../vendor/autoload.php`), or it will not work when the package is actually used in an application (given that I use `require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';` for development on its own). But I want both cases to work just fine.

Comment: `$path = file_exists('vendor/autoload.php') ? 'vendor/autoload.php' : '../../../autoload.php';`

Comment: I see, thanks very much for your time and the details. I thought composer would offer something to deal with this itself. I will update your answer accordingly.